# Woo-Commerce : After Registration redirect to cart page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, redirect, registration

If user is not logged in,there is a registration form on cart page,when submitting, it is redirecting to "my-account page". I want to redirect it to cart page. I have tried so many ways,but did not work.It is forcefully redirecting on my-account. Need Help !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
function custom_registration_redirect() {
   global $woocommerce;
   $cart_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();
   wp_redirect($cart_url);
   exit();
}
add_action('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'custom_registration_redirect', 2);
```

Comment: Yes i have tried this , but still is redirecting it to my-account

Comment: In class-wc-form-handler i print_r() the $redirect , it is showing me cart url , but anyhow it redirects to the my-account

Comment: did you check the settings in admin? https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIKx2.png

Comment: Enable customer registration on the "My account" page.  was not checked , i checked it and test it. It is still not working

Comment: it is custom registration form or woocomerce registraion?

Comment: Nope, I fixed it.

Comment: Above given code is working perfectly

Comment: you are welcome. I updated my answer.